# Dropdown ribbon menu buttons do not fire the click event

Tags: winforms, ribbon

I have a ribbon menu in my application, which has several items. The ribbon elements that have no dropdown items collection, work just fine. 
In the dropdown menus, some items trigger the click event, but most don't.

The issue started appearing on my clients' computers suddenly after some windows updates (May 19th - May 20th 2018). It also happens on my dev machine.

The application is configured to run on .NET Framework 3.5.
I changed to 4.0 on my dev machine, but it didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I am using System.Windows.Forms.Ribbon35.

Answer (score 1):

We are experiencing the same problem with dropdownlist items. What we found so far is that:

1. Clicks, double clicks and mouse up and down do not work on some computers running Windows 10
2. Two similar computers with the same hardware and windows 10 version: one does work and the other does not work
3. Mouse move, mouse enter and mouse leave events do work properly.
4. The click event is actually fired against a panel that is lying behind the dropdown menu